# Can't use lib after import via npm

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm

I'm trying to use flexibility lib inside my Laravel projet. So I ran `npm i flexibility --save` and require it inside my `app.js` file:

```
require('flexibility/flexibility.js');
...
flexibility(document.documentElement);
```

But I receive an alert:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: flexibility is not defined

Comment: Probably you only need to do `require('flexibility')` and not specify the sub file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Require the name of the package, and set it in the window object

In `bootstrap.js`

```js
window.flexibility = require('flexibility');
```

And in `app.js` or from the console

```js
flexibility(document.documentElement);
```

Hope this helps